# Long Loops in Node.js: Yielding Using Timers?

Tags: javascript, node.js, performance

I'm using [Node.js](http://nodejs.org/) to loop through *what could eventually be* a pretty **big array** of posts.

If I were doing something similar using *client side JavaScript*, I would use timers [as explained here](http://oreilly.com/server-administration/excerpts/even-faster-websites/writing-efficient-javascript.html#yielding_using_timers) so as not to block the thread.

My Question is: "Is still a sound practice server side?" or "Should I approach the problem differently?"

Comment: It could be potentially worse on the server because it could block everybody, not just one user.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The proper way to do that in node.js is to break up your work into chunks and use [`process.nextTick`](http://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_nexttick_callback) to queue the next chunk once the current one has completed.  That way you allow other queued callbacks to be executed between each chunk of work.

**UPDATE**: as of Node.js 0.10, [`setImmediate`](http://nodejs.org/api/all.html#all_setimmediate_callback_arg) should typically be used instead of `process.nextTick` for this purpose as `setImmediate` yields to the event loop to make sure I/O is not being starved, but `process.nextTick` doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

JohnnyHK's suggestion is valid. I would consider web workers when the task can be completed later (ie: Added to a queue).

Answer (score -2):

Take a look to [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) library. It provides the async version of the usual collection methods (map, filter, each...). AFAIK, processing your array asynchronously won't block other processes nor users.